# Localisation and Internationalisation in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am developing a PHP website/app that needs to be available in all languages. I intend using the Gettext() method. I need to know how to get through fast ?

Comment: If development speed is an issue, read the original documentation. It's going to be faster than waiting for us to re-type it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at tutorials and the gettext documentation and then ask for help when you encounter any obstacles.

Here you have an example from Sitepoint that I think will be helpful: http://www.sitepoint.com/localizing-php-applications-1/

Comment: Looks like a good start - thanks